# Problema con el Crud cuando creo un plugin en wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugin, crud, href

Me gustaría saber la mejor manera de manejar las URL dentro de un complemento que creo dentro de WordPress, ya que tengo una tabla en la que inserto datos de una clínica y tengo que tener las opciones de: agregar, editar y eliminar.

Para agregar no tengo problemas ya que creé una función para mostrar el formulario desde js pero para editar y eliminar he tenido problemas, ya que la identificación lo recopila con el href:

```php
 <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $obj-> id;?> ">
```

Traté de usar `windows.location` y funciona, pero esta no es una buena solución para un complemento en wp.

A nivel local no tengo problemas, pero en el servidor no puedo enviar la url de esta manera con la identificación, ya que el complemento no me permite dejar la url original del complemento que acabo de crear.
En resumen, me gustaría saber la mejor manera de editar y eliminar dentro del complemento sin tener que ir a otro href.

Comment: gracias por avisar

Comment: Hola, es muy importante revisar [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio, saludos.